# What ratings can Krusty give in The Simpsons: Road Rage?

Tags: the-simpsons-road-rage

After finishing a round of Road Rage mode in The Simpsons: Road Rage, Krusty gives the player a performance rating based on how much money they earned during a single round.

I know from experience that the *Insane* rating is given for earning somewhere between $5,000 and $10,000, but the other ratings are a mystery to me.

**What ratings can Krusty give in Road Rage mode? How much money is needed for each?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IGN has a [walkthrough](http://www.ign.com/faqs/2008/the-simpsons-road-rage-mission-road-rage-faq-858281) that lists these out:

- Loser: $0
- Grandma: $1-$999
- Timid: $1,000-$2,999
- Destructive: $3,000-$4,999
- Reckless: $5,000-$6,999
- Insane: $7,000-$9,999
- Speed Freak: $10,000-$12,499
- Gazelle: $12,500-$14,999
- MADMAN: $15,000+